# Keyup function to save form to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, save

I want to create a function that can automatically save data when the data is completed input. but still not successful. I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

This is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
var vall = $('#dofg_itemcode')

vall.keyup(function(){
            $.post("save-mobile.php?dofgid=<?php echo $dofgid; ?>", {vall : vall.val()}, function(data)) {
              $(".result").html(data);
            }
          }       
}

</script>
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1">
  <table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td width="60%"><span class="style2"><font size="5">QR CODE :</font><br />
        <input  name="dofg_itemcode" type="text" id="dofg_itemcode"  style="width:75%; font-size:30px;" maxlength="15" required="true" tabindex="0"/>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><input id="deviceid" name="deviceid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user;?>" />
        <input id="compid" name="compid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $compid;?>" />
        <input id="tokenid" name="tokenid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tokenid;?>" />
        <input name="alert" type="hidden" id="alert" value="<?php echo $tokenid;?>"/>
        <div id="inlineKeypad"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dofg_itemcode').keyup(function(){
          $.post("save-mobile.php?dofgid=<?php echo $dofgid; ?>", {
                vall : $(this).val();
           }, function(data) {
               $(".result").html(data);
          });
     });
});
```